# Fast CGI Handler not installed in Windows IIS

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I am trying to run a Django app with IIS server. Here are my settings:
Windows Server 2019, IIS 10.\

I am following [this](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject) tutorial.

I am setting up my server and added CGI as shown in the image.

[image]

But, when i deploy the app, i get an error saying that the "FastCgiModule" is not in the list.

[image]

I looked in HandlerMappings to find that the FastCgiModule was indeed not in the list of modules that IIS considers.

Help and understanding about this is much appreciated.

**Things tried**

1. Added wfastcgi.exe path to the system path. Expectation: In case that was the reason FastCGI wasn't being built, this would fix it. Result: No change.
2. Installed ASP.net and .NET frameworks. Expectations: If these are dependencies for the FastCGI framework, it might help install it. Result: No change.

Comment: The FastCGI module is no longer a useful module to use (as PHP/Python on Windows via FastCGI went out of Microsoft support). You should migrate to Linux completely, or use HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/